# Function starts before Storyboard loads

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a main scene and second scene in my storyboard.

When the app first starts, the main scene `viewDidLoad()` function is called. Then, I show the second scene. when I go back to first scene `viewDidLoad()` isn't called.

In the second scene I have implemented the `viewDidDisappear()` function and it updates a database before the scene disappears.

On the main scene I used `viewWillAppear()` function to read the same database, but it doesn't work.

Somehow the main scene `viewWillAppear` is called before the second scene disappear function.  It supposed to be other way around isn't it?

Because when you are going back to first page, active story board is disappear and new one is appear.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, `viewDidLoad` is only called when the view controller is *loaded*; when you return to the existing view controller instance, it isn't *loaded*, the already *loaded* view controller is simply displayed, so what you see is to be expected.

For your second question, look carefully at the function names;

- `viewDidDisappear` - This function will be called *after* the view has disappeared as is implied by *did*
- `viewWillAppear` - This function will be called *before* the view has appeared as is implied by *will*

You say "it updates database before the scene disappears.", but by the function name you can see that it will update the database *after* the view disappears.

You can use the functions `viewWillDisappear` to update the database as this will be called *before* the second view controller disappears, and `viewDidAppear` to update the view *after* the first view controller has re-appeared.

Alternatively you can use a delegation pattern to allow the second view controller to explicitly tell the first view controller (as its delegate) that the data has changed.